# Pygame - How to blit 2 image slides on the screen for x seconds

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to create a sort of logo slideshow (for a couple of seconds) before my game actually starts. So I would boot up the game, logo 1 shows for 2 seconds, logo 2 shows for 2 seconds, then the game starts. How would I go about doing this?

This is what i have tried inside the main loop but the image shows, but doesnt stop after two second:

```
logo = pygame.image.load('logo.jpg').convert()
clock.tick(15)
pygame.time.delay(2)
gameDisplay.blit(logo, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these options:

1. This one is more lengthy but the best and most stable because it checks if the player is trying to exit the application.

   ```
   def intro(clock):
       logo = pygame.image.load('logo.jpg').convert()

       time = (Seconds_You_Want_To_Pause_For)

       while time > 0:

           //Check if player wants to exit
           for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == pygame.QUIT or key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                   sys.exit(), pygame.quit()
                   gameDisplay.blit(logo, (0, 0))

           clock.tick(1)
           pygame.display.update()
   ```
2. This option is short but not very stable. It may cause the application to crash if the player\User try's to click on the exit button or the screen during the introduction.

   ```
   //MUST IMPORT TIME!!!

   import time

   logo = pygame.image.load('logo.jpg').convert()
   clock.tick(15)
   pygame.time.delay(2)
   gameDisplay.blit(logo, (0, 0))
   pygame.display.update()

   time.sleep(Seconds_You_Want_To_Pause_For)
   ```